# What was this king/ warrior's exact name (AGATHOFLIS)

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece, north-africa, sicily

I'm reading some books (in Arabic) about north African history, and exactly the Igilgili (modern day Jijel ) region and I found a story about a warrior / king who tried to conquer the region (4th century B.C) and take it from the Carthaginians. He settled there for a while then went back to Greece. A tribe of Greeks remained there under the name (CHITUÆ).

This king was mentioned to be Sicilian (and probably Greek), and his name (Transcribing exactly from the Arabic) : **AGATHOFLIS/أغاثوفليس.**

I couldn't find any resources in English about him, nor I could write his name correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [Agathocles of Syracuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathocles_of_Syracuse) is the individual being referred to.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I thought I might share where the problem was. The letters ف ''f'' and ق ''qa'' have the same cursive writing with only one additional point over the qa. The writer, when he copied the name, he mistaken the f for a qa which changed Agathokles to Agathofles, haha ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @MCW Good point ! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was a typo. In Arabic language, the letters فـ 'Fa' and قـ 'Qaf' share the same cursive writing, with Qaf having one additional point.

The king is [Agathocles of Syracuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathocles_of_Syracuse).

In the Wikipedia page, the name is correct : **أغاثوقليس**

I would suggest that the name was written in the book with a 'Fa' was due to the bold writing (A point not appearing), or simply a typo (The letters are next to each other on the Arabic keyboard).

Comment: This looks like a pretty good use of a self-answer. Make sure to accept this answer if you are fairly certain this was the issue.